# Can't use Windows.System in C# project

Tags: c#, windows

I am trying to use windows.system.launcher.launchUriAsync(uri)
to open a Skype Uris in a Visual C# console app but i can't and i can't find Windows.System in the available references.I am using Visual Studio 2013.

Can you please help me understand why this happens ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: "Visual C#" is a very generic term...

Answer (score 1):

That assembly (and associated classes and namespaces) are for Windows Store apps **only**.

You cannot use them in a standard C# project.

Reference on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.system.launcher.aspx).

Comment: MSDN even has [pretty pictures](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC716666.png) now... wow

Comment: @felickz, and yet I can't find the blasted link to switch between C#/XAML and Javascript. Priorities wrong much :)

Comment: You have to be hacker to use msdn, just add this to your url:  ?cs-lang=javascript

Comment: @felickz Thats a neat trick! Do you know the one for C#? I mostly find the link in Javascript but need C#.

Comment: If you click those syntax tabs: JavaScript | C# | C++ | VB ... i just appends appropriate value to cs-lang= in the url